# Problems running an AMD R9 390x eGPU on Ubuntu 18.04 with a T470

Tags: drivers, graphics, virtualbox, gpu, gpu-driver

I'm using a Thinkpad T470 which currently is currently dual booted with Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10. Rather than having to boot only one or the other, I'm hoping to run Windows in a VM and pass through an eGPU. I bought an Akitio Node, installed an R9 390x, set it up with booted Windows first (updated Node firmware, installed drivers, etc...), and everything went fine. Booting into Ubuntu, it seems to be detected properly (initially I got a thunderbolt authentication prompt and it shows up under lspci) but it doesn't actually work (no other displays are detected...). I also tried passing it through to a Windows 10 VirtualBox VM (only the display adapter and not sound, could that be it?) and installing drivers but I get `This device cannot start. (Code 10)`. I've got a couple of theories but figured I'd reach out before potentially breaking things:

1. I only passed through the graphics adapter and not the sound device, maybe the Windows VM needs both?
2. The graphics adapter seems to be using a pci-stub driver in Ubuntu, which does not sound like an actual graphics driver. I considered installing the AMD drivers from their website but what I read sounds like Ubuntu should have them installed already.

I'm pretty new to all this, thanks for any help!

`sudo lspci -v` in booted Ubuntu 18.04 (see `0a:00.*`):

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Skylake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=10 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: skl_uncore

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 520 (rev 07) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 144
    Memory at eb000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at e000 [size=64]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [40] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
    Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [ac] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [100] Process Address Space ID (PASID)
    Capabilities: [200] Address Translation Service (ATS)
    Capabilities: [300] Page Request Interface (PRI)
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 122
    Memory at ec220000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/8 Maskable- 64bit+
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 18
    Memory at ec248000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Kernel driver in use: intel_pch_thermal
    Kernel modules: intel_pch_thermal

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 145
    Memory at ec249000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [8c] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me

00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Device 9d3d (rev 21) (prog-if 02 [16550])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 2245
    Flags: 66MHz, fast devsel, IRQ 19
    I/O ports at e060 [size=8]
    Memory at ec24b000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [40] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Kernel driver in use: serial

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port (rev f1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 16
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00002000-00002fff
    Memory behind bridge: 9f800000-9f9fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 000000009fa00000-000000009fbfffff
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Lenovo Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #7 (rev f1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=04, subordinate=04, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: ec100000-ec1fffff
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Lenovo Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Access Control Services
    Capabilities: [200] L1 PM Substates
    Capabilities: [220] #19
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=05, subordinate=3d, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00003000-00004fff
    Memory behind bridge: d4000000-ea0fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000b0000000-00000000d1ffffff
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Lenovo Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Access Control Services
    Capabilities: [220] #19
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1d.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d1a (rev f1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=3e, subordinate=3e, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: ec000000-ec0fffff
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Lenovo Device 2245
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Access Control Services
    Capabilities: [220] #19
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0

00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Sunrise Point-LP PMC
    Flags: fast devsel
    Memory at ec244000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]

00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 64, IRQ 147
    Memory at ec240000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at ec230000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl

00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Sunrise Point-LP SMBus
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 11
    Memory at ec24a000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at efa0 [size=32]
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801

00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I219-LM (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Ethernet Connection I219-LM
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 140
    Memory at ec200000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [e0] PCI Advanced Features
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e

04:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 (rev 3a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 8260
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 146
    Memory at ec100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [40] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Device Serial Number d4-25-8b-ff-ff-9e-0b-06
    Capabilities: [14c] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [154] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi

05:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6240 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (Low Power) [Alpine Ridge LP 2016] (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Bus: primary=05, secondary=06, subordinate=3d, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: d4000000-ea0fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000b0000000-00000000d1ffffff
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [88] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [ac] Subsystem: Device 2222:1111
    Capabilities: [c0] Express Upstream Port, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Device Serial Number 21-df-c0-20-06-c9-a0-00
    Capabilities: [200] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [300] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [400] Power Budgeting <?>
    Capabilities: [500] Vendor Specific Information: ID=1234 Rev=1 Len=0e0 <?>
    Capabilities: [600] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [700] #19
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

06:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6240 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (Low Power) [Alpine Ridge LP 2016] (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Bus: primary=06, secondary=07, subordinate=07, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: ea000000-ea0fffff
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [88] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [ac] Subsystem: Device 2222:1111
    Capabilities: [c0] Express Downstream Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Device Serial Number 21-df-c0-20-06-c9-a0-00
    Capabilities: [200] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [300] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [400] Power Budgeting <?>
    Capabilities: [500] Vendor Specific Information: ID=1234 Rev=1 Len=0e0 <?>
    Capabilities: [700] #19
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

06:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6240 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (Low Power) [Alpine Ridge LP 2016] (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Bus: primary=06, secondary=08, subordinate=3c, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: d4000000-e9efffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000b0000000-00000000d1ffffff
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [88] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [ac] Subsystem: Device 2222:1111
    Capabilities: [c0] Express Downstream Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Device Serial Number 21-df-c0-20-06-c9-a0-00
    Capabilities: [200] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [300] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [400] Power Budgeting <?>
    Capabilities: [500] Vendor Specific Information: ID=1234 Rev=1 Len=0e0 <?>
    Capabilities: [700] #19
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

06:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6240 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (Low Power) [Alpine Ridge LP 2016] (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
    Bus: primary=06, secondary=3d, subordinate=3d, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: e9f00000-e9ffffff
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [88] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [ac] Subsystem: Device 2222:1111
    Capabilities: [c0] Express Downstream Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Device Serial Number 21-df-c0-20-06-c9-a0-00
    Capabilities: [200] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [300] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [400] Power Budgeting <?>
    Capabilities: [500] Vendor Specific Information: ID=1234 Rev=1 Len=0e0 <?>
    Capabilities: [700] #19
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

07:00.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation JHL6240 Thunderbolt 3 NHI (Low Power) [Alpine Ridge LP 2016] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Device 2222:1111
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at ea000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
    Memory at ea040000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [88] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [c0] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=16 Masked-
    Capabilities: [100] Device Serial Number 21-df-c0-20-06-c9-a0-00
    Capabilities: [200] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [300] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [400] Power Budgeting <?>
    Capabilities: [500] Vendor Specific Information: ID=1234 Rev=1 Len=088 <?>
    Capabilities: [600] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Kernel driver in use: thunderbolt
    Kernel modules: thunderbolt

08:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL6340 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Alpine Ridge 2C 2015] (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Bus: primary=08, secondary=09, subordinate=3c, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00003000-00003fff
    Memory behind bridge: d4000000-e9efffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000b0000000-00000000d1ffffff
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [88] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [ac] Subsystem: Device 1cf0:0308
    Capabilities: [c0] Express Upstream Port, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Device Serial Number 4f-41-85-01-55-e9-07-00
    Capabilities: [200] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [300] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [400] Power Budgeting <?>
    Capabilities: [500] Vendor Specific Information: ID=1234 Rev=1 Len=0d8 <?>
    Capabilities: [600] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [700] #19
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

09:01.0 PCI bridge: Device 0086:0000 (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
    Bus: primary=09, secondary=0a, subordinate=0a, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00003000-00003fff
    Memory behind bridge: d4000000-d40fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000b0000000-00000000c07fffff
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [88] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [ac] Subsystem: Device 1cf0:0308
    Capabilities: [c0] Express Downstream Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Device Serial Number 4f-41-85-01-55-e9-07-00
    Capabilities: [200] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [300] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [400] Power Budgeting <?>
    Capabilities: [500] Vendor Specific Information: ID=1234 Rev=1 Len=0d8 <?>
    Capabilities: [700] #19
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

0a:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Hawaii XT / Grenada XT [Radeon R9 290X/390X] (rev 80) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: PC Partner Limited / Sapphire Technology Grenada XT2 [Radeon R9 390X]
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 18
    Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=8M]
    I/O ports at 3000 [size=256]
    Memory at d4000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
    Expansion ROM at d4060000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [48] Vendor Specific Information: Len=08 <?>
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [58] Express Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
    Capabilities: [150] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [200] #15
    Capabilities: [270] #19
    Capabilities: [2b0] Address Translation Service (ATS)
    Capabilities: [2c0] Page Request Interface (PRI)
    Capabilities: [2d0] Process Address Space ID (PASID)
    Kernel driver in use: pci-stub
    Kernel modules: radeon, amdgpu

0a:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Hawaii HDMI Audio [Radeon R9 290/290X / 390/390X]
    Subsystem: PC Partner Limited / Sapphire Technology Hawaii HDMI Audio [Radeon R9 290/290X / 390/390X]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 148
    Memory at d4040000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [48] Vendor Specific Information: Len=08 <?>
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [58] Express Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
    Capabilities: [150] Advanced Error Reporting
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

3e:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Intel Corporation Device f1a5 (rev 03) (prog-if 02 [NVM Express])
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 390a
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18, NUMA node 0
    Memory at ec000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=16 Masked-
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [158] #19
    Capabilities: [178] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [180] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel driver in use: nvme
    Kernel modules: nvme
```

and

[Windows 10 Device Manager Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cm0tG.png)